# finding records matching particular keyword from an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am having a problem in the program code as I have changed my file into an array but not sure whether it has been changed or not. So please check the code given below also it is showing an error of use of uninitialized @data in last line.

Now after this, my biggest problem is that I want to collect only those elements within an array which have a specific keyword in between them.  For example, each array's element starts from where `women` ends and  `children` begins.  These words are common in all the other elements but information in between them are different and I want only those elements which has a keyword 'factor  man' somewhere in between so I want to extract not all but only those elements which are having keyword 'factor  man'.

As you can see that my file is having all the initial words common in all the elements but after that the information is different but each element has a start from `women` and ends at `children`. please anyone could guide me regarding this.Thanks in advance.

Input file

```
women bds1
origin USA
accession not known
factor xyz
work abc
children
women sds2
origin ENG
accession known
factor man
work wwe
children
women cfc4
origin UK
factor xxx
work efg
children
women gtg6
origin UAE
factor man
work qqq
children
```

script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ifh;
my $line = '';
my @data;

my $ifn  = "fac.txt";

open ($ifh, "<$ifn") || die "can't open $ifn";
my $a = "women  ";
my $b = "children ";
my $_ = " ";
while ($line = <$ifh>)
{
chomp 
   if ($line =~ m/$a/g); {
     $line = $_;

   push @data, $line;

while ($line = <$ifh>) 
{
    $line .= $_;

push @data, $line;

last if 
($line =~ m/$b/g);
}

}

push @data, $line; }


print @data;
```

output

```
women  sds2
origin  ENG
accession known
factor  man
work  wwe
children
women  gtg6
origin  UAE
factor  man
work  qqq
children
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @AoH;#Array of hashes
my $ifn  = 'fac.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $ifn or die "Failed to open $ifn: $!";

my $i = 0;
while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    my @flds = split;
    $AoH[$i]{$flds[0]}{content} = $flds[1];
    $AoH[$i]{$flds[0]}{seqnum} = $.;
    $i++ if $flds[0] eq 'children';
}

foreach my $href (@AoH){
    if (${$href}{factor}{content} eq 'man'){
        foreach my $k (sort {${$href}{$a}{seqnum}
                        <=> ${$href}{$b}{seqnum}} keys %$href){
            my $v;
            if (defined ${$href}{$k}{content}){
                $v = ${$href}{$k}{content};
            }
            else{
                $v = ' ';#Space if undefined
            }
            print "$k $v\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Revised program to output hash key value pairs in same sequence as they occur in input file.

Comment: Thank you for the help. As I am a beginner in perl could you please explain me the above code given by you in more elaboration form as will this code give me the above mentioned output also I am unaware with the terms used in the code of yours could you please give me knowledge of them by explaining it more. As I am confused the need to use 'seqnum'. I will be grateful to you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I tested the script and it gives the desired output. My first try gave the desired output, but not in the same sequence as in the input. That is why I added a 'seqnum' key to the hashes stored in the array. The value of seqnum is the line number corresponding to the input record. Hashes don't preserve the sequence in which the data is stored, so we have to sort the hash elements by input line number to restore the original sequence in which they occurred in the input (for example, 'children' must be the last key in each group.)

Comment: To store the data in such a way as to be able to select elements according to a specified key ('factor') having value ('man') we need some kind of data structure within the array. In this case the structure is an array containing a reference to hashes, each of which contains a reference to another hash. For an explanation of this data structure, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES

Comment: Hello d5e5, I am running this program it is giving me errors starting from chomp line till eq 'children' about the use of uninitialised value $_ in scalar chomp..use of uninitialised value $_ in split...use of uninitialised value $flds[0] in hash elements...use of uninitialised value $flds[0] in string eq...could you please check them....thank you

Comment: hello d5e5, could you please tell me that my data is just in the form of a file so will it be turned to AOH by this code given by you. Also which of the line in code is valid for 2 or more elements-  $AoH[$i]{$flds[0]}{content} = $flds[1];
    $AoH[$i]{$flds[0]}{seqnum} = $.; please explain me these lines and the function of $. I would be highly thankful to you for all the knowledge provided by you in order to clear my concepts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $. is a special variable in Perl whose value is the current line number for the last filehandle accessed. see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html